# How to validate Flask form upon submitting?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, flask-wtforms

I have generated a Flask form to register a new User in my CRUD app. However, the Flask form shows error even after all the data fields are filled. I have even included the `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in HTML code. Also, this abnormal behavior started all of a sudden. It worked fine for the first 2 times when I added 2 new users.

The following are the codes I am using - `routes.py`

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    regpass=app.config['REGISTRATION_KEY']
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.passkey.data==regpass:
            user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
            user.set_password(form.password.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        flash('Invalid Passkey!')
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

`forms.py`-

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    passkey = PasswordField('Pass Key', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

`config.py` -

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    REGISTRATION_KEY=os.environ.get('REGISTRATION_KEY')
```

HTML -

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<br><hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 id="signin">
                Register!
            </h1>
            <hr>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="row" id="form">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32 , class_='form-fields') }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            {{ form.email.label }}<br>
            {{ form.email(size=64, class_='form-fields') }}<br>
            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32, class_='form-fields') }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            {{ form.passkey.label }}<br>
            {{ form.passkey(size=32, class_='form-fields') }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span id='submit-field'><p >{{ form.submit(class_='submit-button-login') }}</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I have the REGISTRATION_KEY in the `config.py` file. Before starting the flask app, I set the `REGISTRATION_KEY` in the terminal.
Here is the image that shows the error .
[image: Error image]

Thank and regards.

Comment: @RajaSimon I feel so stupid now. I skipped the html part for password2. This should not have been posted here. Should I delete the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Flask Form you have set password2 field required but in html you've not declare the form tag and hence the error. Adding `{{ form.password2...` will solve the problem.